# Laravel - DB Query items based on pivot table status

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I have in my app a list of modules that players are able to complete, and when they do, they have to stop appearing in the "available modules" list. I have the table "players", "modules" and "module_player" to save the relation.

So, for the "available modules" list I only want to show modules that haven't been started yet (aka no record on the module_player table) or have been started but not finished yet (aka status 1 in module_player table).

Lets say I have:

players table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Player_1 |
| 2 | Player_2 |

modules table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Module_1 |
| 2 | Module_2 |
| 3 | Module_3 |

module_player table

| module_id | player_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

The "available list" should return only the module 1 (started but not finished) and the module 3 (not started).

Problem is I'm only getting the module 1 in the "available list", this is the query I have with obviously has something wrong in it:

```
        $modules = \DB::table('modules')
            ->join('module_player', 'modules.id', '=', 'module_player.module_id', 'left')
            ->join('players', 'module_player.player_id', '=', 'players.id', 'left')
            ->where('module_player.status', '!=', 2)
            ->where('module_player.player_id, '=', 1)
            ->select('modules.id', 'modules.name', 'modules.image', 'modules.mandatory')->paginate(10);
```

Thanks

Comment: why are you not using the relations?

Comment: hmm because I want to get not only the modules that have relation with the player but also modules that doesn't have relation yet, and paginated

Comment: so you want the modules which status is 1 in module_player and which are not exist in this table. like 1 and 3?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using

```
`where('module_player.player_id, '=', 1)`
```

You will get only records where player_id is 1 so try the below query with `whereNotIn`

```
$modules = \DB::table('modules')
                ->join('module_player', 'modules.id', '=', 'module_player.module_id', 'left')
                ->join('players', 'module_player.player_id', '=', 'players.id', 'left')
                ->whereNotIn('modules.id', function($query){
                     $query->select('module_id')
                     ->from('module_player')
                     ->where('status', 2);
                })
                ->select('modules.id', 'modules.name', 'modules.image', 'modules.mandatory')->paginate(10);
```

if you want it for any particular user you can pass player_id in `use()`

```
->whereNotIn('modules.id', function($query) use($player_id){
                         $query->select('module_id')
                         ->from('module_player')
                         ->from('player_id', $player_id)
                         ->where('status', 2);
                    })
```

Comment: Thanks, first one works. Would love a little explanation as why, because I thought no matter which user was logged in, the results would be the same (that's why I used the line you removed).

But I tried starting/completing different modules with two different users and the results are alright. I don't see in the query how could it know that , for example, player 1 has module 1 completed and 2 started and player 2 has module 1 started and nothing else if I'm not using the logged in player_id anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove `->where('module_player.player_id, '=', 1)` line as it will return records with player_id 1. and try below query

```
$modules = \DB::table('modules')
            ->join('module_player', 'modules.id', '=', 'module_player.module_id', 'left')
            ->join('players', 'module_player.player_id', '=', 'players.id', 'left')
            ->where('module_player.status', '!=', 2)
            ->select('modules.id', 'modules.name', 'modules.image', 'modules.mandatory')->paginate(10);
```